# Maven adds '-windows' to the artifact name when downloading a snapshot artifact

Tags: maven-2, repository, nexus

I have added a bunch of artifacts to my local Nexus Maven repository.
When I build my project I get the following error:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Building pronto-web Java EE 6 Webapp
>   [INFO]    task-segment: [verify]
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
>   [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
>   [INFO] Copying 4 resources
>   [INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
>   [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
>   [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Source\Pronto\pronto\pronto-web\target\classes
>   [INFO] [antrun:run {execution: remove-javax}]
>   [INFO] Executing tasks
>   [INFO] Executed tasks
>   [INFO] [gwt:compile {execution: default}]
>   [INFO] using GWT jars from project dependencies : 20100714-SNAPSHOT
>   [WARNING] You should not declare gwt-dev as a project dependency. This may introduce complex dependency conflicts
>   **Downloading: http ://mercury:8980/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/20100714-SNAPSHOT/gwt-dev-20100714-20100715.053026-1-windows.jar**
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] artifact not found - Unable to locate resource in repository
>
> Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
>
> Then, install it using the command:
>      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.gwt -DartifactId=gwt-dev -Dversion=20100714-20100715.053026-1 -Dclassifier=windows -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
>
> Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
>      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.gwt -DartifactId=gwt-dev >-Dversion=20100714-20100715.053026-1 -Dclassifier=windows -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
>
> com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:20100714-20100715.053026-1
>
> from the specified remote repositories:
>    releases (http://mercury:8980/nexus/content/groups/public),
>    all (http://mercury:8980/nexus/content/groups/all),
>    snapshots (http://mercury:8980/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots)
>
> http ://mercury:8980/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/20100714-SNAPSHOT/gwt-dev-20100714-20100715.053026-1-windows.jar
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 8 seconds
>   [INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 15 08:57:29 CEST 2010
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 50M/614M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Has anyone an idea why maven thinks there should be '-windows' added to the artifact name?
(Downloading: http ://mercury:8980/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/20100714-SNAPSHOT/gwt-dev-20100714-20100715.053026-1-windows.jar)

If I browse the repository it contains the artifact but without the '-windows' suffix.

Older versions of this artifact were platform dependent and had 'windows' or 'linux' or 'mac' as classifier but recent versions are platform independent and I don't have any such classifier in my poms.

PS:
I added a space in each URL between the protocol and the colon because I didn't yet receive enough reputation to post links.

Comment: Try running mvn -U - maybe maven relies on the old snapshot POM. "windows" in your case is probably a classifier, it must be configured in your POMs somewhere, analyze them carefully.

Answer (score 3):

The following dependency must be declared somewhere, very likely as a transitive dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
  <version>20100714-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>windows</classifier>
<dependency>
```

I suspect a bad pom if artifacts are not platform dependent anymore.

Is there any more recent snapshot you can use?

Comment: Thank you Pascal and Lexicore for your quick responses.  
I am sure there never was such classifiere element anywhere in the artifacts I deployed to the repository nor in my projects pom (only in some older versions in public repositories).  

I deleted the com/google subdirectory in my local .m2 directory just in case and now the problem vanished.

Maybe I should just have renamed it to have it available for further investigation but didn't expect that this really solves the problem.

Comment: After some maven configuration changes, artifact updates and switch to Maven 3 I had this error again. Cleaning the .m2 directory did not work this time.
It seems, that the gwt-maven-plugin caused this error.
I updated it from 1.2 to 1.3-SNAPSHOT and now the error is gone again.

Comment: @devde: Comparing the poms of both versions of the plugin would be interesting. But it's weird anyway. And maybe you should post this comment as answer and accept it.